# I can't select appended element before reload page in query

Tags: jquery, append, selector

this function append elements :
! i need select a.commentdelete tag before reloading page!!!

```
var item = "<a class='commentdelete' id='";
item += '95';
item += "'>delete</a>";
var maindiv = '#'+module_id;
//alert(maindiv);
$(maindiv).append($("<div class='commentdiv'></div>")
    .html(item)
    .fadeIn('slow'));
```

i need to select one of elements that appended before reload page by this code:

```
$('.commentdelete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var comment_id = $(this).attr('id');

    alert();
    //deleteComment_ajax(user, comment_id);
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but as a note you can minimize your first 3 lines with this : var item = "<a class='commentdelete' id='95'>delete</a>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$(document).on("click", '.commentdelete', function(e){
   //do work
});
```